# Увеличение размера динамического массива c-style строк

Tags: c++, c, массивы, строки, динамические-массивы

Динамический массив интов можно увеличить в размерах нехитрым способом:

```
int *doubleSize(int *arr, int sz)
{
    int *arr2 = new int[sz * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    arr2[i] = arr[i];
    delete[] arr;
    return arr2;
}
```

Помогите написать аналогичную функцию для массива с-строк, заданного следующим образом:

```
char **id = new char*[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    id[i] = new char[4];
}
```

Comment: В чем проблема? Вместо = strcpy.

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka, копировать строки необязательно, можно скопировать лишь указатели. Он, ведь, хочет расширить массив, а не сделать его копию. А значит, старые указатели вполне могут перекочевать в новый массив.

Answer (score 2):

Да, в общем-то, все то же самое:

- Создаете новый массив new char*[sz*2];
- В него копируете указатели на с-строки из старого массива;
- Убиваете старый массив;
- Возвращаете указатель на новый массив.

Только имейте в виду: что в примере с int, что со строками, новые элементы (те, что не скопированы) остаются неинициализированными (мусор). По-хорошему их надо инициализировать.